# How to set reply_to/reply-to using SparkPosts Ruby API client?

Tags: ruby, email, sparkpost

It seems like I can't set `reply_to` in `vals` hash when I'm using `SparkPost::Client.new().send_message(param1,param2,etc...)`. Egs here: https://github.com/SparkPost/ruby-sparkpost

Meaning, when I send an email through the client - I want the end-user (that receives the email) to automatically have the `reply_to` attr (NOT the `from` attr) fill out the *Reply To:* field for a given ESP.

I've also seen this: https://github.com/SparkPost/ruby-sparkpost/blob/master/examples/transmission/with_template.rb. Which uses `send_payload`.

Does anyone know how to set the `reply_to`so it doesn't simply default to the `from`'s email address?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out.  Currently, you **must** use the `SparkPost::Client.new().transmission.send_payload` method and build the payload yourself.

Example:

```
payload = {
  recipients: [{tags:[tag1,tag2],address:{email:foo@bar.com}}],
  content: {
    from: "Someone <no-reply@somewhere.io>",
    subject: "Your awesome subject",
    reply_to: "Someone Else <totally.hit.me.up@somewhere.else.io>",
    html:"<h1>Hello World</h1>"
  }
}
SparkPost::Client.new().transmission.send_payload(payload)
```

Comment: Not sure if you use templates, but you can also set the reply_to on a template. This isn't supported by the SparkPost UI yet, but you can update it with the API: https://developers.sparkpost.com/api/#/reference/templates